# Update From Angular 4.2 to Angular 9.0 + Jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I developed one system 2 years ago with Jhipster   4.6.0 and added material angular 2.0.0-beta.12.

So, today I want to make an update for the whole system.
I've started to migrate with support of https://update.angular.io/#4.2:5.2,

At this point I ask me, I'll need to update jhipster-generator?, for example, JhiHttpInterceptor uses the old HTTP Angular Client or I need to make my own implementation?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
/**
 * A HTTP interceptor responsibility chain member is a class, which may react on request and response of all requests
 * done by HTTP.
 */
export declare abstract class JhiHttpInterceptor {
    private _successor;
    successor: JhiHttpInterceptor;
    processRequestInterception(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
    processResponseInterception(response: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response>;
    abstract requestIntercept(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
    abstract responseIntercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response>;
}
```

I understand that my system is very outdated, now I'm updating my code from 4.2 to 5 when I'll get Angular 6 I'll use ng update.

Any recommendations or advice with Jhipster?

Comment: Have you tried to first run `jhipster upgrade` ? It should upgrade both frontend and backend.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to update to angular 9 because some of the changes are yet to be finalized yet. Refer Screenshot below -

[image: Still Some Of the angular 9 Changes are yet to be finalized]

You can update to Angular 8 by referring this guide -

[Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/).